# restore SharePoint web site issue

Tags: windows-server-2008, sharepoint-2007

I am using SharePoint Server 2007 Enterprise with Windows Server 2008 Enterprise. And I am using publishing portal template.

I have a source web site called http://server1/site1, and I want to restore it to another machine whose URL is http://server2/site2.

I want to know in stsadm -o restore, how to specify the destination changed URL?

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is:

```
stsadm -o restore -url http://destinationsiteurl/ -filename backupfilename.bak
```

where 'destinationsiteurl' is the url of the location you want to restore to and 'backupfilename.bak' is the name of the backup file you are restoring from. For example if your backup file was called site1.bak the syntax would be

```
stsadm -o restore -url http://server2/site2/ -filename site1.bak
```

If you get a message saying that the destination site already exists you have to add the -overwrite qualifier eg

```
stsadm -o restore -overwrite -url http://server2/site2/ -filename site1.bak
```

There's a great write up on this functionality as well as the GUI backup and restore [here](http://jamesmckay.net/2007/05/moving-a-sharepoint-site-theres-an-easy-way-and-a-hard-way/).

The full list of properties and methods for stsadm is at Microsoft [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288413.aspx).

Comment: If I need to change the url at the destination machine, I need to backup/restore at site collection level other than site level?

Comment: Question answered!